# Jenkins job wait for multiple open executor slots

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a generic job 'build' which is called by a concrete build for each codeline, e.g. 'stable_build'.  I have stable_build trigger build and have 'Block until the triggered projects finish their builds' checked, so that stable_build's result will mirror build's result.  This means that whenever I execute stable_build, it requires 2 executor slots, one for stable_build and one for build.  I have another job 'stable_tests' which triggers 'tests' in a similar fashion.  The problem I'm facing is this: if stable_build and stable_tests are executed simultaneously, each will take up an executor slot while the downstream 'build' and 'tests' are in the queue.

Is there a way in Jenkins to configure a job to wait for 2 open executor slots, or perhaps another workaround?

Comment: Are you using a slave node or are you running from the master? I think you can configure three+ executors

Comment: I'm running everything from master.  I can increase the number of executors, but there will still be the race condition.  Also this was a simplified example; in reality I working with 5 codelines and 5 jobs per codeline.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin capable of doing this:

Heavy Job Plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Heavy+Job+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the number of executors... this is set in Manage Jenkins > Configure System > # of executors

See this thread for more details: [Jenkins - maximum number of concurrent jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626899/jenkins-maximum-number-of-concurrent-jobs)

Comment: I did this initially, but this does not avoid the race condition where 'stable_build' and 'stable_tests' are building and 'build' and 'tests' are in the queue. Also this was a simplified example; in reality I working with 5 codelines and 5 jobs per codeline.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to ascertain exactly what you're trying to do here (perhaps you could elaborate) but have you explored the `build other projects` option in the `post-build actions` section?

You can specify a comma-separated list of jobs that are tied to the master job. There is a handy `trigger only if build succeeds` option too.