# run multi job of multi jobs on jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I want to build multiple jobs in jenkins:

[image]

I install multi job plugin on jenkins. When I build `test_all_jobs`, it run job1 and freeze on it and doesn't start job1-1 until I close job1 test!

Actually I want to start job1-1 then job 1-2 and after they finished job 2-1 then job2-2 should start.

I should say I can not use Build Flow Plugin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I **don't** use the multi job plugin. Instead, I use the combination of the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) and the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).
I think together, you get much more flexibility and ease of configuring your desired flow.

Look into these and see if you can get the answer you want from joining them.

I hope this helps.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, appropriate settings of number of threads in the node are also required.

Comment: What do you mean by "number of threads in the note"? In the Jenkins build?

Comment: This I don't know how to control. Why do you need it?

Comment: `This I don't know how to control.` - [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626899/jenkins-maximum-number-of-concurrent-jobs) is related. `Why do you need it?` you shouldn't, if you don't need it. But it seemed to me that for simultaneous execution several tasks, you need more than one executor. But it looks like I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks all, I change `of executors` in jenkins and all of my job run.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this issue  is because of the number of executors assigned to the slave node on which you are running the job is assigned with 1.
Under nodes---->select your node ----> Configure ---> Increase the no of executors
[image: Under nodes---->select your node ----> Configure ---> Increase the no of executors]

Hopefully this helps you.